# about satellite is it possible to get signal from two satellite at a time?

Tags: satellites

1. Is it  possible to get signal from two satellites at the same  time?
2. If we go far away from a certain country to another, and be able to continue to recieve the same signal?

Comment: What type of satellites do you mean? GPS satellites? Television satellite? Something else? Also, Question 3 seems a little unclear to me, could you rephrase that?

Comment: This question will find more people equipped to comment on it and help you improve it in [space.stackexchange](http://space.stackexchange.com). It can be migrated there if you want; simply click the `flag` button to call for a moderator's help.

Answer (score 2):

1. It is definitely possible for a particular spot on Earth to get signal from more than one satellite at the same time (indeed, this is essential for things like [GPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Space_segment)). Whether a particular device can lock onto more than one signal is, of course, completely dependent on the device.
2. It depends on the type of satellite and on how far you go. [Geostationary satellites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit) remain always in a fixed position with respect to land, and if you go *too* far away from under it then you'll stop seeing it; because geostationary orbits are very far from Earth you would need to travel several thousand kilometers for this to happen. Satellites on [low Earth orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit) go round the Earth in about 90 minutes per orbit, so that they fly over most countries with equal likelihood. Communications satellites tend to be on geostationary or at least geosynchronous orbits.
3. Satellites definitely can communicate with other satellites via radio signals; some of them do this regularly. Cool examples of this are [GRACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Recovery_and_Climate_Experiment) and [GRAIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRAIL), but this is also used regularly for communications purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if they are accurate but here they go, and you should have asked this question on network.se

> is it possible to get signal from two satellite at a time?

Yes, the GPS uses three satellite at a time to predict your position

> if we go far away from India to another country will we be able to get signal from Indian satellite?

If you are in the range of it then yes if not then no

> )whether the satellite sent to another satellite signals?

yes they do mostly, for example you watching a live telecast of a show happening in America sitting in china, and our friends the three GPS satellite also communicate with each other for knowing their relative position to each other

Comment: Minor correction: a GPS requires 3 satellites to give you a 2D position on earth, a 4th is required for 3D positions. See [this link](http://www.gps.gov/multimedia/poster/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast satellites tend to restrict their signal to a given geographic area.  This can be to make a stronger signal available where it is desired or to eliminate interference with other satellites.  Coverage maps for GSAT-14, to be launched in May, are shown at the bottom of [this brochure](http://www.isro.org/gslv-d5/pdf/brochure.pdf)  You may be able to receive the signals near the designated coverage area, but they will fall off as you get outside.